# Conflicting dependencies with Google-Ads 21.0.0 deploying in Google Cloud

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-ads-api

I'm trying to update my Google Ads library as it is needed to use newer versions of Google Ads API.
When I run the code locally it works smoothly, however, when I try to deploy it in Google Cloud it prompts a dependencies error:

```
The conflict is caused by:
    The user requested protobuf==4.22.3
    google-ads 21.0.0 depends on protobuf >= 4.21.5
```

The libraries I'm trying to update are:

```
google-ads==21.0.0
google-api-core[grpc]==2.11
google-auth==2.17.3
protobuf==4.22.3
proto-plus==1.22.2
```

The libraries I was using previously:

```
google-ads==17.0.0
google-api-core[grpc]==2.8.2
google-auth==2.9.0
protobuf==3.20.0
proto-plus==1.19.6
```

Is there any way I can work around this error? I know the code works.

Thanks,

A.